# Is this always true, that if managedobjectcontext change then something must be deleted, updated, or added?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
NSUInteger numberOfChanges = moc.insertedObjects.count + moc.deletedObjects.count+moc.updatedObjects.count;

if (numberOfChanges ==0 )
{
    NSAssert([moc hasChanges]==false,@"[moc hasChanges]==false");
    return;
}
```

Somehow the assertion fail. I wonder why. So nothing is inserted. Nothing is deleted. Nothing is updated. Yet [moc hasChanges] is true? This happens very rarely. However, it should not have happened at all.

This is the full code if people want to see.

```
+(void)commit {

    [BGHPTools breakIfLock];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSArray * arUpdatedObjects = moc.updatedObjects.allObjects;

    NSArray * arUpdatedObjectsID = [arUpdatedObjects convertByPeformingSelector:@selector(objectID)];
    NSUInteger numberOfChanges = moc.insertedObjects.count + moc.deletedObjects.count+moc.updatedObjects.count;

    if (numberOfChanges ==0 )
    {
        //NSAssert([moc hasChanges]==false,@"[moc hasChanges]==false");
        return;
    }
    if (arUpdatedObjectsID.count) {
        while (false);
    }

    [BGFetchClass vAddObjectIDCachesForArray:moc.insertedObjects.allObjects];
    [BGFetchClass vDeleteObjectsForArray:moc.deletedObjects.allObjects];
    /*if (numberOfChanges ==0 )
    {
        NSAssert([moc hasChanges]==false,@"[moc hasChanges]==false");
        return;
    }*/
    //NSAssert([moc hasChanges],@"[moc hasChanges]==true");
    __block NSError *error;

    __block BOOL saveSuccesfully;

    [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
        @synchronized([BGFetchClass class])
        {
            saveSuccesfully = [moc save:&error];
            if (!saveSuccesfully) {
                CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }];

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        if (arUpdatedObjectsID.count) { //When we're adding new objects, this won't be called. That is the only time commit is called while we are synching
            [BGHPTools vDoForeGroundAndWait:^{
                NSManagedObjectContext * moc =[BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler managedObjectContext];
                for (NSManagedObjectID * moi in arUpdatedObjectsID) {
                    NSManagedObject * mo = [moc existingObjectWithID:moi error:nil];
                    NSAssert(mo!=nil, @"Object can't possibly be nil");
                    [mo turnToFault];
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext * parentMoc = [self managedObjectContextMainContext]; //Main parent is not nsmainqueueconcurency type. Hence, this is save
    [parentMoc performBlockAndWait:^{
        if (![parentMoc save:&error])
        {
            CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);// handle error
        }
    }];
    NSAssert(error==nil, @"Error must be nill");
}
```

Comment: Is this iOS or OSX? You would need to provide more code (or a concise sample project) for someone else to debug this unfortunately

Comment: When do you run this code? Is this when you receive a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`? Maybe it's when you receive a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`? Some other time? It's important.

Comment: I run this code when I want to commit the changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is one documented situation that can give you this behavior.
From `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation:

[NSManagedObjectContext deletedObjects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deletedObjects)

> Discussion
>   The returned set does not necessarily include all the objects that have been deleted (using deleteObject:)—if an object has been inserted and deleted without an intervening save operation, it is not included in the set.

Could it be your case?

Comment: I never delete a manageObject in any cases. Is this the only case we can think off?

Comment: I suppose I will put more commit and try to pin point this my self.

Comment: I suggest you to not lose so much time around this. I played a lot with Core Data and, although it's great, I've found a lot of small bugs and discrepancies with the documentation. For example, I took the time to try exactly this extract of the doc, and it seems not true!! If I insert and delete an object without saving, the count of deletedObjects is correct (1). It seems that the more affordable method is hasChanges, but you can simply save even if no changes occurs and still live happy :-)

Answer (score 1):

`NSManagedObjectContext.hasChanges` turns `YES` even if you do this:

```
managedObject.someAttribute = managedObject.someAttribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSManagedObject` sometimes fails. try using:

```
- (BOOL)hasAnythingChanged {
    return [[[self changedValues] allKeys] count] > 0;
}
```

(self being your NSManagedObject)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that changing a property and then changing it back to its last saved value would leave the NSManagedObject dirty. Either that was the intended behavior or I did something wrong along the way. I ended up checking on the [changedValues count] which worked for me but you would have to think about checking for any transient properties yourself since they won't appear in 'changedValues' and will make your NSManagedObject dirty.